# Angle between two circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, tikz-angles

I am trying to recreate this image in LaTeX:

[image]

So far, I have the following:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (2,3) circle (1.5cm); 
    \draw (4.5,3) circle (1.5cm); 

    \draw[red] (2,3)--(4.5,3)--(3.25,3.85)--cycle; 
    \filldraw[red] (2, 3) circle (1pt) node[left] {$c_{1}$};    
    \filldraw[red] (4.5, 3) circle (1pt)node[right] {$c_{2}$};  

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the `\theta` angle be between two sides of the red triangle? This would sound reasonable, but it not clear from your drawing.

Comment: it is supposed to be the angle between the two circles. I forgot to include a separate angle that will be between the two sides of the triangle.

Comment: I think the angle should be the one between the tangents at the intersection point.

Answer (score 6):

I thought (but could be wrong) the angle between two circles was defined as the angle between the tangents to the circles from that run through the intersection of the tangents to one circle that runs through the center of the other circle. The `intersections` library is not needed to construct this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R1=2;R2=2;d=3.6;},
    shorten both/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]
 \path[nodes={circle,draw,inner sep=0pt}] 
   (0,0) node[minimum size=2*R1*1cm] (c1){}
   (d,0) node[minimum size=2*R2*1cm] (c2){}; 
 \draw[blue,shorten both=-1cm] 
   (tangent cs:node=c2, point={(c1.center)}, solution=2)
  coordinate (t2) -- (c1.center) -- (c2.center)
   -- (tangent cs:node=c1, point={(c2.center)}, solution=1)
  coordinate (t1);
 \path (intersection cs:first line={(c1)--(t2)},second line={(c2)--(t1)}) coordinate (i); 
 \draw[red,shorten both=-1cm] (i)  -- (tangent cs:node=c1, point={(i)}, solution=2) 
    coordinate (t1');
 \draw[red,shorten both=-1cm] (i)  -- (tangent cs:node=c2, point={(i)}, solution=1)
    coordinate (t2');
 \path  pic ["$\theta$", draw=red,angle eccentricity=1.5,angle radius=0.6cm]  {angle = t2'--i--t1'};    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: @sigur and @frougon proposed another well-defined prescription: the angle between the tangents to the circles at the point at which the circles intersect. This is just to say that this angle can be computed analytically very easily, so one does not need to use any libraries. (I am not saying that using libraries is a disadvantage.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R1=3;R2=2;d=3.5;},
    dot/.style={circle,inner sep=0.6pt,fill}]
 \path[nodes={circle,draw,inner sep=0pt}] 
   (0,0) node[dot,label=below:$c_1$]{} node[minimum size=2*R1*1cm] (c1){}
   (d,0) node[dot,label=below:$c_2$]{} node[minimum size=2*R2*1cm] (c2){};
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{(R1/d*R1-R2/d*R2+d)/2}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{sqrt(R1*R1-\myx*\myx)}
 \path (\myx,\myy) node[dot](i){};
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myalpha}{asin(\myy/R1)}  
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybeta}{180-asin(\myy/R2)}  
 \draw[red] (c1.center) edge[black] (i) (c2.center) edge[black] (i)
 (i)  ++ (-90+\myalpha:1)  edge[blue] ++(90+\myalpha:2)
 (i)  ++ (90+\mybeta:1) edge[blue] ++(-90+\mybeta:2)
 arc[start angle=-270+\mybeta,end angle=-90+\myalpha,radius=1]
 node[midway,below]{$\theta\pgfmathparse{\myalpha+180-\mybeta}
 =\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if there is an official definition of “angle between two circles.” One can certainly define the angle between the curves where they intersect. This is one thing. One can draw an arc “at some point” between the curves, which I did as it seemed to be what the OP wanted. Your idea is also a meaningful possibility! If there was a clear definition, it would have been quite desirable to state it in the question, as this is not a math forum. I did ask for precisions there, but got minimal input in return. :-/

Comment: One sure thing: this question has a high (collective effort)/(OP's effort) ratio!

Comment: @frougon I agree, of course. If you do a Google image search for "angle between two circles" then the interpretation of this post shows up quite a few times. From the hand drawn figure one cannot say much, the results look very similar. I also agree with your second comment but this is generally the case here, i.e. in many posts the question leaves a lot of work for the ones who answer them.

Comment: Too lazy to do the search (and busy with something else), I trust you on this!

Comment: I think the angle should be the one between the tangents at the intersection point. The same as the angle between two curves.

Comment: @Sigur There are now several tangents in this construction. Here it is the angle between the red tangents.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, yes, I see. I think the OP wants the angle between two curves, in this case, particularly, two circles. The angle is the same at both intersection points, by symmetry.

Comment: @Sigur frougon and justonly have such solutions. (My problem with this interpretation is that this does not define a unique angle.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AngleOfIntersectionOfTwoCircles/

Comment: @sigur the title of the animation is "angle between intersections of two circles" but this is also a well-defined angle, just less reminiscent of the OP's drawing.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, the OP draw is not precise, the lines looks tangent to circles but the angle looks in the luna sector.

Comment: @Sigur and Schrödinger'scat Sorry to pollute here. I think there was a little misunderstanding, because this morning I drew “what the OP wanted” (not mathematically sound) + another construction (like others did). And when Zarko asked me, I said that the angle between tangents at the intersection *could* be correctly defined. But I had not drawn it because this doesn't go with what the OP drew (he or she didn't even draw said tangents)! Now I've added numbered sections, clarified what section 1 does (a drawing) and added a new figure in section 2 with a well-defined angle (not the same...

Comment: ... as the one chosen by Schrödinger's cat, so all the choices are now on the table! :-)

Comment: @frougon I had upvoted your answer before I wrote mine. Should I click on the upvote button again? (It may cost you 10 points. ;-)

Comment: Hey, I didn't write this for an upvote. Just so that things are clear. :) (I don't want esteemed people to think I pretended to represent something whereas I drew something else... In short, it's a simple question of honor like in XVIIIe's century Barry Lyndon, etc. Life and Death, nothing more :-).

Comment: @frougon I was just kidding. ;-)

Comment: Yep, yep, got it, don't worry. :-) I removed unused objects from my fig in section 2, because the red triangle had really nothing to do with the blue angle. (today has been terrible for upvotes, I hope not too many people are in hospital... or worse)

Comment: @frougon Since this question has gotten so little attention I added an analytic variant of one of your variants... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

What is angle between circles is not clear, so below is solution for angle at top of triangle determined by intersection of tangents on circles from opposite circles origins:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                calc,
                intersections,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=0.5pt, outer sep=0pt},
  C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=3cm}
                        ]
\coordinate[dot,label=left :$c_1$] (c1) at (0.0,0)  {};
\coordinate[dot,label=right:$c_2$] (c2) at (2.5,0) {};
\node (C1) [C] at (c1) {};
\node (C2) [C] at (c2) {};
\node[dot] at (c1) {};
\node[dot] at (c2) {};

\draw[name path=A, shorten > = -10mm] 
    (C2) -- (tangent cs:node=C1, point={(C2)}, solution=1) coordinate (t1);
\draw[name path=B, shorten > = -10mm]
    (C1) -- (tangent cs:node=C2, point={(C1)}, solution=2) coordinate (t2);
\draw[name intersections ={of=A and B, by=C}] 
     pic ["$\theta$", draw=red!30]  {angle = c1--C--c2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\draw[densely dashed, very thin]    
    (c1) -- (t1) node[dot,label=$t_1$] {}
    (c2) -- (t2) node[dot,label=$t_2$] {};
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
MWE doesn't generate showed image. This is now corrected. Beside this are add marks tangents points.

Answer (score 2):

## 1 Angle mark drawn between two circles

In this section, I'm only trying here to faithfully reproduce what was asked in the question. This is a *drawing*; it is quite accurate, but the figure is not necessarily interesting from a mathematical point of view. The arc angle, i.e. the (arc length)/(arc radius) ratio corresponding to the red angle mark depends on the chosen radius (i.e., on where on the circles one decides to place points `A1` and `A2`—see below). Therefore, it is probably not a great idea to call this an “angle between two circles.” (question title). See sections 2 and 3 below, and other answers like [Schrödinger's cat's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537115/73317) for different interpretations of the question, where the chosen angle only depends on the circles.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, intersections, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small, my circle radius/.initial=2.5cm]
\coordinate (O1) at (2,3);
\coordinate (O2) at (6,3);

\begin{scope}[nodes={circle, draw, inner sep=0,
              minimum width=2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my circle radius}}]
  \node (C1) at (O1) {};
  \node (C2) at (O2) {};
\end{scope}
\path[name path=C1border] (O1)
  circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my circle radius}];
\path[name path=C2border] (O2)
  circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my circle radius}];

\coordinate (M1) at (tangent cs:node=C1, point={(O2)}, solution=1);
\coordinate (M2) at (tangent cs:node=C2, point={(O1)}, solution=2);

\path[name path=p1] (M1) -- (O2);
\path[name path=p2] (M2) -- (O1);
\path[name intersections={of=p1 and p2}] (intersection-1) coordinate (M);

\draw (M) edge ($(M1)!-2.5!(M)$) edge ($(M2)!-2.5!(M)$);
\draw[red] (O1) -- (O2) -- (M) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}[fill=black, every circle/.style={radius=1pt}]
  \fill (O1) circle node[below left] {$\mathcal{C}_{1}$};
  \fill (O2) circle node[below right] {$\mathcal{C}_{2}$};
  \fill (M1) circle node[inner sep=0, xshift=0.3ex, above=0.8ex] {$M_1$};
  \fill (M2) circle node[inner sep=0, xshift=-0.3ex, above=0.8ex] {$M_2$};
\end{scope}

\coordinate (A1) at (C1.30);
\coordinate (A2) at (C2.150);
\path[name intersections={of=C1border and C2border}] (intersection-1)
  coordinate (X);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[red] let \p1=($(A1)-(X)$), \p2=($(A2)-(X)$), \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},
               \n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)}, \n3={veclen(\p1)} in
  (A2) arc[start angle=\n2, end angle=\n1, radius=\n3]
  node[red, midway, inner sep=0, below=0.3ex] {$\theta$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a larger angle mark radius, simply move  points `A1` and `A2`. For instance, with:

```latex
\coordinate (A1) at (C1.15);
\coordinate (A2) at (C2.165);
```

one obtains:

[image]

Note: `15` and `165` are polar angles for points `A1` and `A2` on each on the respective circles (they are border anchors of circle nodes).

## 2 Angle between two tangents (a)

The blue angle drawn in this section only depends on the circles.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, intersections, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small, my circle radius/.initial=2.5cm]
\coordinate (O1) at (2,3);
\coordinate (O2) at (6,3);

\begin{scope}[nodes={circle, draw, inner sep=0,
              minimum width=2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my circle radius}}]
  \node (C1) at (O1) {};
  \node (C2) at (O2) {};
\end{scope}
\path[name path=C1border] (O1)
  circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my circle radius}];
\path[name path=C2border] (O2)
  circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my circle radius}];

\begin{scope}[fill=black, every circle/.style={radius=1pt}]
  \fill (O1) circle node[below left] {$\mathcal{C}_{1}$};
  \fill (O2) circle node[below right] {$\mathcal{C}_{2}$};
\end{scope}

\path[name intersections={of=C1border and C2border}] (intersection-1)
  coordinate (X);
\draw[dashed] (O1) -- (X) -- (O2);
\path (O1) -- (X) -- ([turn]-90:3cm) coordinate (B2);
\path (O2) -- (X) -- ([turn]90:3cm) coordinate (B1);
\draw[blue] (B1) -- (X) -- (B2);
\pic["$\theta$" color=blue, draw=blue, angle radius=0.25cm,
     angle eccentricity=1.8] {angle=B1--X--B2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with `angle radius=0.6cm`:

[image]

## 3 Angle between two tangents (b)

The red angle drawn in this section only depends on the circles.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, calc, intersections, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\coordinate (O1) at (2,3);
\coordinate (O2) at (6,3);

\begin{scope}[nodes={circle, draw, inner sep=0, minimum width=2*2.5cm}]
  \node (C1) at (O1) {};
  \node (C2) at (O2) {};
\end{scope}

\coordinate (M1) at (tangent cs:node=C1, point={(O2)}, solution=1);
\coordinate (M2) at (tangent cs:node=C2, point={(O1)}, solution=2);

\path[name path=p1] (M1) -- (O2);
\path[name path=p2] (M2) -- (O1);
\path[name intersections={of=p1 and p2}] (intersection-1) coordinate (M);

\draw (M) edge ($(M1)!-2.5!(M)$) edge ($(M2)!-2.5!(M)$);
\draw[red] (O1) -- (O2) -- (M) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}[fill=black, every circle/.style={radius=1pt}]
  \fill (O1) circle node[below left] {$\mathcal{C}_{1}$};
  \fill (O2) circle node[below right] {$\mathcal{C}_{2}$};
  \fill (M1) circle node[inner sep=0, xshift=0.3ex, above=0.8ex] {$M_1$};
  \fill (M2) circle node[inner sep=0, xshift=-0.3ex, above=0.8ex] {$M_2$};
\end{scope}

\pic["$\theta$" color=red, draw=red, angle radius=0.25cm,
     angle eccentricity=1.8] {angle=O1--M--O2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: off-topic: first solution is meaning leas (it is not clear, what OP means with "angle between circles"). There `\theta` present angle between two secants, so it is determined by points of crossing secants of circles. With other words, those points are infinity many.

Comment: @Zarko The radius of the arc drawn in red is arbitrary, but the angle between two regular curves at a point where they intersect is very well defined (given proper orientation on the curves, etc.). Just imagine drawing the tangents where the two circles intersect.

Comment: Are you sure? Well, I will left this to OP (since this off-topic here). But, can you draw this angle for bigger angle locus radius?

Comment: Sure, just look at the latest edit.

Comment: Thank you! Now you just confirm now my claims, but let us left this to OP :-)

Comment: @Zarko Note that when you mark an angle between two intersecting lines or segments, the arc radius is just as arbitrary. What is not arbitrary in this case (lines or segments) is the (arc length)/(arc radius) ratio, i.e.: the angle measure in radians.

Comment: @Zarko I believe we had a misundersting this morning, so I tried to clarify: 1) In the text of my section 1, I now clearly explain that I'm just trying to reproduce what the OP approximately drew, even if this doesn't illustrate a well-defined angle. 2) But I've added section 2, which represents the well-defined angle I mentioned in [my earlier comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537054/angle-between-two-circles/537081#comment1356966_537081). I had not drawn it before because clearly, the OP didn't draw anything required for its construction.

Answer (score 1):

I have a more generic version to offer.

You only have to set the radius and the center of both circles. All other parameters are derived from these numbers.

In contrast to your solution the `intersections` library calculates the point where the circles intersect.

[image: s]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, math}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm]

        \tikzmath{
            coordinate \C{1-center}, \C{2-center};
            \C{1-center} = (2,3);
            \C{2-center} = (5,3);
            \r{1} = 2;
            \r{2} = 2;
            \r{angle} = 1;
        }

        \foreach \i in {1,2} {
            \draw[lightgray, name path global=C\i] (\C{\i-center}) coordinate(C\i-center) circle[radius=\r{\i}]; 
        }

        \draw[name intersections={of=C1 and C2, by=X}] 
            foreach \i in {1,2} { (X) -- ($(X)!-0.5!(C\i-center)$) };

        \draw[red] (C1-center) node[left] {$c_{1}$} -- 
            (C2-center) node[right] {$c_2$}  -- 
            (X) node[above, fill=white, fill opacity=0.7, text opacity=1] {$c_3$} -- cycle; 

        \foreach \i in {{C1-center}, {C2-center}, X} {
            \filldraw[red] (\i) circle (1pt);
        }

        \draw[blue] 
            let \p{1} = (C1-center), 
                \p{2} = (C2-center), 
                \p{3} = (X), 
                \n{start} = {-180+atan2(\y{3}-\y{1}, \x{3}-\x{1})}, 
                \n{end} = {-180+atan2(\y{3}-\y{2}, \x{3}-\x{2})} in 
            ($(X)!\r{angle} cm!(C1-center)$) arc[start angle=\n{start}, end angle=\n{end}, radius=\r{angle} cm] coordinate(T1) 
            ($(X)!\r{angle} cm!(C1-center)!0.5!(T1)!0.3!(X)$) node{$\theta$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

From wolfram.com :

> The angle of intersection of two overlapping circles is defined as the
>   angle between their tangents at either of the intersection points.
>   When the angle is 180°, we say that the circles are tangent. When the
>   angle is 90°, we say that the circles are orthogonal.

Important definition because it allows to study the "conservation of angles" by the transformation called "inversion". Circles and angles are conserved.

The case with orthogonal circles makes the definition interesting.

With this definition, I can propose a solution with a new package `elements`. This package is the successor of `tkz-euclide`, a simpler version with only the centimeter as a unit and independent of `tkz-base`.
Of course the code compiles with `tkz-euclide`.

**A)**

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,6/0/B,4/2/C}
\tkzDrawCircles(A,C B,C)
\tkzDefTangent[at=C](A) \tkzGetPoint{a}
\tkzDefPointsBy[symmetry = center C](a){d}
\tkzDefTangent[at=C](B) \tkzGetPoint{b}
\tkzDrawLines[add=1 and 4](a,C  C,b)
\tkzDrawSegments(A,C B,C)
\tkzFindAngle(b,C,d)
\tkzGetAngle{bcd}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=.5](b,C,d)
\tkzFillAngle[fill=MidnightBlue,opacity=.2,size=1cm](b,C,d)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.25](b,C,d){\small $\bcd^\circ$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**B)**

It's interesting to verify the result with two orthogonal circles.
Now the point C is defined by the macro ` \tkzDefCircleorthogonal from=B

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{elements}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,6/0/B,4/2/D}
\tkzDefCircle[orthogonal from=B](A,D)
\pgfnodealias{C}{tkzFirstPointResult}
\tkzDrawCircles(A,C B,C)
\tkzDefTangent[at=C](A) \tkzGetPoint{a}
\tkzDefPointsBy[symmetry = center C](a){d}
\tkzDefTangent[at=C](B) \tkzGetPoint{b}
\tkzDrawLines[add=1 and 4](a,C  C,b)
\tkzDrawSegments(A,C B,C)
\tkzFindAngle(b,C,d)
\tkzGetAngle{bcd}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=.5](b,C,d)
\tkzFillAngle[fill=MidnightBlue,opacity=.2,size=1cm](b,C,d)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.25](b,C,d){\small $\bcd^\circ$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]